# Combining two small scripts in VBA for Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am a VBA novice, and have two small scripts that both work independently, but I am unable to get them both working at the same time (because I'm not sure how to do it!)

Script 1:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, Range("AE49")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Select Case Target.Value
       Case 1
          Range("A50:A52").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          Range("A53:A55").EntireRow.Hidden = True
       Case 2
          Range("A50:A53").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          Range("A54:A55").EntireRow.Hidden = True
       Case 3
          Range("A50:A54").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          Range("A55").EntireRow.Hidden = True
       Case 4
          Range("A50:A55").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End Select
End Sub
```

Script 2:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, Range("AE25")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Select Case Target.Value
       Case 1
          Range("A26:A28").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          Range("A29:A35").EntireRow.Hidden = True
       Case 2
          Range("A26:A29").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          Range("A30:A35").EntireRow.Hidden = True
       Case 3
          Range("A26:A30").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          Range("A31:A35").EntireRow.Hidden = True
       Case 4
          Range("A26:A31").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          Range("A32:A35").EntireRow.Hidden = True
       Case 5
          Range("A26:A32").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          Range("A33:A35").EntireRow.Hidden = True
       Case 6
          Range("A26:A33").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          Range("A34:A35").EntireRow.Hidden = True
       Case 7
          Range("A26:A34").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          Range("A35").EntireRow.Hidden = True
       Case 8
          Range("A26:A35").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End Select
End Sub
```

I have these loaded directly into the 'View Code' bit of the VBA Editor, as I don't know how to use modules.

I also want another script that will unhide row 41 if the value of Z40 is either PowerPoint or Verbal, and will hide row 41 if the value of Z40 is None.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that ought to be pretty basic :

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call Script1(Target)
    Call Script2(Target)
End Sub


Private Sub Script1(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, Range("AE49")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Select Case Target.Value
       Case 1
          Range("A50:A52").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          Range("A53:A55").EntireRow.Hidden = True
       Case 2
          Range("A50:A53").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          Range("A54:A55").EntireRow.Hidden = True
       Case 3
          Range("A50:A54").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          Range("A55").EntireRow.Hidden = True
       Case 4
          Range("A50:A55").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Script2(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, Range("AE25")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Select Case Target.Value
       Case 1
          Range("A26:A28").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          Range("A29:A35").EntireRow.Hidden = True
       Case 2
          Range("A26:A29").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          Range("A30:A35").EntireRow.Hidden = True
       Case 3
          Range("A26:A30").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          Range("A31:A35").EntireRow.Hidden = True
       Case 4
          Range("A26:A31").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          Range("A32:A35").EntireRow.Hidden = True
       Case 5
          Range("A26:A32").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          Range("A33:A35").EntireRow.Hidden = True
       Case 6
          Range("A26:A33").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          Range("A34:A35").EntireRow.Hidden = True
       Case 7
          Range("A26:A34").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          Range("A35").EntireRow.Hidden = True
       Case 8
          Range("A26:A35").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End Select
End Sub
```